# Linear gradient not working with div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I am creating trapezoid using following CSS:

```css
.trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

The linear-gradient attribute is not working. I want the trapezoid as shadow i.e its color should eventually fade away. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: it won't work beause the height is 0

Comment: ..and you can't have gradient borders.

Comment: Can anyone suggest some work arounds with minimal change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a transform on a suitably sized element (or pseudo-element).

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(40deg);
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton :) very simple and elegant solution! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply gradient in this way as you are using border and your element has a height of 0 so background won't be visible.

Instead you can try to use multiple gradient to create the shape:

```css
.trapezoid {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,white 50%,transparent 52%) 100% 0/40px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,white 50%,transparent 52%) 0 0/40px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

Or use clip-path:

```css
.trapezoid {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

Another method with skew and pseudo-element:

```css
.trapezoid {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.trapezoid:before,
.trapezoid:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  transform:skew(20deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
}
.trapezoid:after {
  left: 0;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

Comment: Hi Can you please explain your code as well? Regarding what attribute are forming the trapezoid?

Comment: @user3681970 i used 3 gradient, the main one, and 2 with white color to hide the non-needed part, then simply adjust the value to see ;) i also added another solution